# Flutter Chat App or Messaging App Notification

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am making a chat app with flutter. I used `StreamBuilder` to receive messages and store them in Firestore.

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                stream: FirestoreHelper.firestoreHelper
                    .getMessageStream(widget.chatRoomModel.chatRoomId),
                builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {})
```

I want to include notifications in my app.

What should I use and what should I read. I am a junior flutter developer and I do not have any idea about notification.

Comment: Ah come on Frank, you know you could have provided a canonical answer! Would love to see an episode of Flutter Build dedicated to this. My app saves a users messages to a collection named on a hash of their firebaseIds, then I push messages as records to that collection, each message using a timestamp for Id. This is a lot of dynamic naming and I do not understand how to send notifications on that. I know a little Flutter, not backend stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[Chat app article on Medium](https://medium.com/@duytq94/flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages-a26c669f4675)

1. The app explained there uses: [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin to
   register push service and listening notification coming.
2. Cloud Functions fire a callback when it is triggered by an event — new
   document is added.
3. local_notifications to render our local
   notification when app in the foreground.

If you've found a better way, that's more up to date than the 2019 article, please answer your own question. I'm beginning work on it too.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you may try [flutter_apns](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_apns)

For Android, you may try [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

They both based on Google Firebase Cloud Messaging, Flutter Fire.

You should set up FlutterFire CLI firstly, with [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli)

Then implement [Google FCM](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview)